# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies in solution with multiple depencencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, dll, static-libraries

I have a solution in Visual Studio with three projects added to it. The first project is a C# WinForms project with it's dependency set to the second project. The second project is a VC++ project which compiles to a DLL.

This VC++ project is dependent on another VC++ project which is a static library. I am able to run the executable from the debug/release folder directly on the development system.

But when I try to test on a different computer, I get an error after UI loads saying "Could not find file or assembly "mydll.dll" or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

Both the VC++ projects have their output set to a specific folder. When I right click in the references and check path, it looks fine.

What must I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try opening the csproj file in a test editor like Notepad or Notepad++ and figure out if the references are pointing to the right dll(s). Also pay attention as some of the references might include signatures, and it might not be the right signature either.

What shows up on the IDE might not be exactly the same that you have on the csproj file.

You need to unload the project from VS to be able to edit it in a text editor.

Also do this for all the projects on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did the other computer have the Microsoft C++ Redistributable installed, of the appropriate version (year) and architecture?   Also you can investigate dependencies with dumpbin.

Comment: Yes. The other computer has Microsoft C++ Redistributable installed. I'll look into the tool you mentioned.